# `plnkr` - getting error as `Unexpected token export` while export a typescript `interface`

Tags: typescript, angular, plunker

I created a `angular2` app in `http://plnkr.co/edit`. all are works fine. I tried to export a `interface`, i am getting error as `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export` - i don't know the wrong what here going on really.

any one help me to sort this issue. which i provided the path is correct to `import` the `list-item`.

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/02vEl2o5UKQwswrPKlI5?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Look at this working demo - is this what you want???](http://plnkr.co/edit/S4Dwj0dqhxuaiMLgfWYH?p=preview).

I hope now  you can carry on with the solution if it is what you wanted.

```
export class ShoppingListComponent {

  listItems = new Array<ListItem>();

  selectedItem = ListItem;  //problem is here.

  selectedItem:ListItem;   // this is solution

  onItemAdded(item:ListItem) {
    console.log(item);
    this.listItems.push({name:item.name,amount:item.amount});

  }

};
```

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
meta: { 'src/list-item.ts': { format: 'es6' }},
```

to your SystemJS config

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kOGLF4i5ZXhAyMaJYcS6?p=preview)

Could also be related to https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T1151